# библиотеки java

Tags: java, javafx

Уже как полтора месяца я занимаюсь самостоятельным изучением java, знаю основной синтаксис и даже написал морской бой в текстовом варианте, но когда я хочу повторить это в графическом интерфейсе, то происходят какие-то танцы с бубном, вот например библиотека javafx, откуда я должен узнать о нескольких десятков специальных слов, благодаря которым и происходит все взаимодействие? например мне нужно получить координаты мыши на игровом поле. Есть какой-то источник, где все нормально сгруппированно?

Comment: java и графический интерфейс не то чтобы большие друзья, как раз из-за тонкостей внутри gui библиотек.

Comment: https://www.ozon.ru/search/?text=javafx

Comment: @venäjä men А в той книге, откуда, как я догадываюсь, вы почерпнули пример морского боя, разве нет продолжения в последующих главах перевода игры в JavaFX?

Comment: Наиболее продвинутый вариант это читать [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm). Для введения в библиотеку JavaFX можно посмотреть какие-то видео-уроки, почитать о том что такое "Model-View-Controller" (MVC) паттерн (часто используется для разработки графических приложений).

Comment: Прекрасная (на мой вкус) книжка, где всё толково и по порядку изложено -- Kishori Sharan, "Learn JavaFX 8"